# Multi-table delete query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a 3 table database, and am attempting to delete from all of these tables with one query.

Query:

```
DELETE FROM cranes 
JOIN craneparts ON cranes.id = craneparts.craneID 
JOIN parts ON parts.id = craneparts.partsID 
WHERE cranes.id = '$id'`
```

Can anyone help with as to why this query isn't working? $id is simply a PHP integer, and for my testing purposes `$id = 2`

The given error is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN craneparts ON cranes.id = craneparts.craneID JOIN parts ON parts.id = crane' at line 1`]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query must be specific about which tables you want it to delete from, even if you want to delete from all tables.

```
DELETE cranes, craneparts, parts
FROM cranes JOIN craneparts ON cranes.id = craneparts.craneID 
JOIN parts ON parts.id = craneparts.partsID 
WHERE cranes.id = '$id'
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html for more documentation.

Comment: Thanks. That fixes problem one but now I get this error

`Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ('smithsv1'.'craneparts', CONSTRAINT 'fk_craneparts_cranes1' FOREIGN KEY ('craneID') REFERENCES 'cranes' ('ID') ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

EDIT: Fixed error code blocking

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to control the order of the table deletion in multi-table delete. You should define your foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the tables you want to delete from after the `delete`:

```
DELETE cranes, craneparts, parts
    FROM cranes JOIN
         craneparts
         ON cranes.id = craneparts.craneID JOIN
         parts
         ON parts.id = craneparts.partsID
     WHERE cranes.id = '$id';
```